# Can't connect to the Internet, maybe a DNS problem?

Tags: linux, dns, fedora, internet-connection

I'm using Fedora 15 with the latest updates on a HP Mini 210 Netbook.

My internet was working fine. Then all of a sudden it stopped working on my Fedora netbook. I also have an iMac and can connect that to the internet without any problem. So my Internet connection is working fine on the iMac.

However, when I put the cable in my Fedora netbook. I get the IP address through DHCP and DNS automatically. This is the same setting as my iMac. I also have a Windows partition on my Fedora netbook. That works fine, so there is no hardware problems.

I can ping the router fine, but cannot ping `www.google.com` or browse any websites.

`nslookup google.com` returns "cannot find host name google.com". So I think there is something wrong with the DNS.

`resolv.conf` doens't have any DNS address, as they are assigned using DHCP.

Could anyone tell me some steps to take to try and solve this problem?

Comment: if they were assigned by dhcp they would still show up in resolv.conf try editing it manually

Comment: PS can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If DHCP is not properly assigning your DNS, you can manually edit resolv.conf to include, oh,

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

or you could substitute the IP address of your router, e.g. 192.168.1.1

The two servers listed above are public DNS servers provided by Google, which are supposed to automatically provide very fast service based on your geographic/network location.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I added that directly into the resolv.conf file and restart NetworkManager.